# How to detect if an image contains only white color with C++

Tags: c++, qt, image-recognition

We are writing a piece of software which downloads tiles from the internet from WMS servers (these are map servers, and they provide images as map data for various locations on the globe) and then displays them inside a window, using Qt and some OpenGL bindings.

Some of these servers contain data only for specific regions on the planet, and if you request and area outside of what they support it they provide you just a blank white image, which we do not want to use since they occupy extra space. So the question is:

How to identify whether an image contains only 1 color (white), or not.

What we have tried till now is the following:

1. Create a `QImage`, loop over every pixel of it, see if it differs from white. This is extremely slow, and since we want this to be a more or less realtime application, this idea sadly does not work.
2. Check if the image size is the same as an empty image size, but this also does not work, since it might happen that:

- There is another image with the same size which actually contains data
- It might be that tiles which are over an ocean have just one color, a light blue, and we need those tiles.

3. Do a "post processing" of the downloaded images and remove them from the scene later, but this looks ugly from the users' perspective that tiles are just appearing and disappearing ...
4. Request transparent images from the WMS servers, but due to some OpenGL mishappenings, when rendering, these images appear as black only on some (mostly low-end) video cards.

Any idea, library to use, direction or even code is welcome, and we need a C++ solution, since our app is C++.

**Edit** for those suggesting to sample pixels only from a few points in the map:

[image: corner of Norway] and [image: Line in the map]

The two images above (yes, the left image contains a very tiny piece of Norway in the corner), would be eliminated if we would assume that the image is entirely white based only sampling a few points, in case none of those points actually touch any color than white. Link to the second image: https://wms.geonorge.no/skwms1/wms.sjokartraster2?LAYERS=all&SRS=EPSG:900913&FORMAT=image/png&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=-313086.067812500,9079495.966562500,0.000000000,9392582.034375001&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&TRANSPARENT=false

Comment: Please show exactly how you did #1.  If you're invoking per-pixel calls then yes it will be slow.  Also, it will be slow if you have not compiled with full optimizations enabled.  You can easily test for white pixels by walking over the raw image buffer and seeing every byte is 0xff (assuming 8-bit integer RGB data, that is).  Regarding your "realtime" requirement, testing every pixel of an image should be vastly quicker than actually _downloading_ the image!!!  For more practical/useful suggestions specific to your task, describe the actual format of the data you're processing.

Comment: If all the white image files are exactly the same (probably after removing all meta data which may include date/time etc information), use file size + check several pixels (or use file thumbnail or hashing algorithms).

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Qt, but could QImage::createMaskFromColor() help? It seems to allow you to pick a color that will create a transparency mask for the image. This doesn't help identify the wasted space, but it could hide the squares for post-processing to clean up.

Answer (score 0):

The correct and most reliable way would be to uncompress the PNG bytes and check each pixel in a tight loop.

The most usual source of an image process routine being "slow" is invoking a function call per-pixel.  So if you are calling `QImage::pixel` in a nested loop for each row/column, it will not have the performance you desire.

Instead, take advantage of the fact that QImage gives you raw image bytes via the `scanLine` method or the `bits` method:

Something like this might work:

```
const int bytes_per_line = qimage.bytesPerLine();

unsigned char white_row[MAX_WIDTH * 4];
memset(white_row, 0xff, sizeof(white_row));

bool allWhite = true;
for (int row = 0; allWhite && (row < height); row++)
{
    unsigned char* row_data = qimage.scanLine(row);
    allWhite = !memcmp(row_data, white_row, bytes_per_line);
}
```

The above loop terminates pretty fast the moment a non-white pixel is encountered.